# Use phantomjs to drive chrome

Tags: phantomjs

Is there a way to use phantomjs to drive my firefox/chrome browser?

We have a bunch of casperjs tests, that I would like to run directly in the browser for debugging ( or just pure interrest ).

I seem to recall that a long time ago, before phantomjs became pure headless, I could do this by making it run on X instead of xvfb and removing/uncommenting the phantom.exit() line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PhantomJs IS a browser, so the answer is no. You may want to look into [Karma](http://karma-runner.github.io/) however.

You just use a [config](https://karma-runner.github.io/latest/config/browsers.html) file which allows you to provide a browser to run your tests in:

- Chrome
- ChromeCanary
- Firefox
- Opera
- Safari (only Mac)
- PhantomJS
- IE & Edge (only Windows)
- SauseLabs, BrowserStack Electron, & [more](https://www.npmjs.com/browse/keyword/karma-launcher)

Still, your tests will need to be written in QUnit, Jasmine, Mocha, ... which can be too much work to port from CasperJs.